# Can't add class to d3 svg image

Tags: d3.js

I am using a world flags sprite sheet from https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite to add flag images to my force-directed graph. When I follow the instructions it works just fine on an image element I created in html. I added the link to the head of my html file. When I tried it out on the img with the "hello" id, it worked fine. You can see it below.

```
<div class="f32">
<svg width="960" height="600"><img id="hello"/></svg>
</div>

 d3.selectAll("#hello")
   .attr("class", "flag us")
```

But the flag image is not appearing on the following

```
 var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("image")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("image")
  .attr("id", "hello")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)
```

When I try setting the class to a single image element I created in d3, it still does not work:

```
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(60, 60)")
.append("image")
.attr("id", "hello")
```

Comment: This won't work. The sprites' CSS relies on the `background` property to set the actual image. However, this property is not [valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/attindex.html) in the SVG namespace and can thus not be applied to an `<image>` element.

Comment: thank you. i found a workaround but it's good to know for future purposes.

Comment: Would you mind writing a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) sharing your solution with the community?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I ended up not using the sprite sheet, what I did was just use images that were available at http://flags.fmcdn.net. To get the right image to match each country I just input the country code that was available from my json api into the end of the url, just before .png.

```
 var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("image")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return "http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/"+d.code+".png"})
  .attr("width", 30)
```